# dynamic JSON parsing android

Tags: android, json, parsing

here i am developing an application having lot of forms like registration form ...
forms should be designed dynamically depending upon web service (JSON) data.

web service will have some kind of info like

username : textbox
gender : dropdown

etc...

according to web service i have to design form dynamically.
forms field can be changed or updated from server side so design should be dynamic.

**so question is :----
what should be my json web service structure.
and what would be the way to fetch data from that web service in android...**

Comment: Refer to [this link](http://json.org/) and [this link](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: I hope this tutorial will be help you : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/